# R ggplot2 worldmap. breaks in legend

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, legend

I´m trying to produce a worldmap using ggplot2 in R. It schould be a countrybased heatmap. The data I'm working on comes from twitter and I want to show where the tweets come from. There are 2 problems:

1. the integrated data

   ```
   map_data("world")
   ```

   gives me a map older the 20 years (USSR).

   ```
   map_data("world2")
   ```

   seems damaged. or there is some ordering issue but I don't know how to solve it.

http://schloegl.net/supersambo/world2.pdf

1. I would like to change the colour breaks and don't know how to access it. Since Brazil is the only country easy to read it would be important to edit the breaks and show the difference between countries with less then 1000 tweets.

http://schloegl.net/supersambo/world.pdf

here is my code

```
    WD <- getwd()
    if (!is.null(WD)) setwd(WD)

    library(maps)
    library(plyr)
    library(ggplot2)

    twitter=read.csv("/Users/stephanschloegl/Studium/Diplomarbeit/rawData/c_userInfo/c_userInfo.csv",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,sep=";")

    #read geodata
    cities=read.csv("GeoWorldMap/cities.txt",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,sep=",")
    countries=read.csv("GeoWorldMap/countries.txt",header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,sep=",")

    #find countries for twitter$timezone
    lista <- twitter$time_zone
    country_ids <- cities$CountryID[match(lista,cities$City)]
    country <- countries$Country[match(country_ids,countries$CountryId)]

    #FREQENCIES
    frequencies <- as.data.frame(table(country))
    names(frequencies) <- c("region","freq")
    #change 0's to NA
    frequencies$freq[frequencies$freq==0] <- NA

    #load world data
    world <- map_data("world2")
    #Delete Antarctica
    world <- subset(world,region!="Antarctica")


    #merge twitterdata and geodata
    world$tweets <- frequencies$freq[match(world$region,frequencies$region,nomatch=NA)]

    map <- qplot(long, lat, data = world, group = group,fill=tweets,geom ="polygon",ylab="",xlab="")
    #this does'nt work
    map + scale_colour_hue(name="Number of\nTweets",breaks=levels(c(10,20,100,200,1000)))
    map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `scale_colour_hue()` is for discrete scales. You have to use `scale_fill_gradient()` because you want to change the fill not the outline.

```
    map + scale_fill_gradient(name="Number of\nTweets", trans = "log",
                           breaks = c(10, 20, 100, 200, 1000))
```

There you go. You have also put levels in the breaks which makes no sense, the number of tweets is numeric.

[image]

You can get the new map [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/vnzkTX3huF0) and follow the instructions in that post to make it work.

Comment: hi, I already thought there may be problems with the scale comand. But unfortunatly this doesnt make any difference either. here is my data   http://158.255.212.46/supersambo/Map.zip (8MB)

Comment: Try ussing trans = "log" inside the call. That way you can actually see the difference between 10 and 20. I have not tried with your data.

Comment: here is my result. trans="log" made no difference. http://158.255.212.46/supersambo/Rplot.pdf

Comment: thanks a lot. another error I made was putting the trans="log" option behind breaks.

Comment: any suggetion for the world2 problem? or where to get a newer world map?

Comment: According to the help world and world2 are the same map but the later is centered at the pacific. I updated the answer with the source of up to date map.

Comment: thank you but installing this package and all its dependencies really seems complicated.

Comment: An old thread but here is a great description of how to fix the "world2 problem" that I believe you are describing. http://cameron.bracken.bz/finally-an-easy-way-to-fix-the-horizontal-lines-in-ggplot2-maps